# Counting mongoengine ListField elements

Tags: django, django-models, mongoengine

I`m having a hard time migrating my models from standard Django orm with MySQL to **mongoengine-odm**.

I have the following model that works fine in the old structure:

```
class Place(Document):

    name    = StringField()
    acronym = StringField()

    parent = ReferenceField('self')
    hierarchy = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))
    hierarchy_size = IntField()

    @classmethod
    def preSave(instance, sender, **kwargs):
        instance.hierarchy_size = len(instance.hierarchy)

signals.pre_save.connect(Place.preSave, sender=Place)
```

But when working with the new mongoengine, I'm facing problems to access the objects hierarchy size in the way I was doing before. Receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/awesome_user/workspace/awesome_project/project/models.py", line 728, in importPlacesFromMySQL
    myCountry.save()
  File "/Users/awesome_user/workspace/awesome_project/site_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 220, in save
    signals.pre_save.send(self.__class__, document=self)
  File "/Users/awesome_user/workspace/awesome_project/site_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/base.py", line 267, in send
    for receiver in self.receivers_for(sender)]
  File "/Users/awesome_user/workspace/awesome_project/project/models.py", line 804, in preSave
    instance.hierarchy_size = len(instance.hierarchy)
TypeError: object of type 'ListField' has no len()
```

Does anyone know how to access the properties of the instance, like the **length** in my case?

Comment: Does `len(list(instance.hierarchy))` works?

Comment: No, it returns -> TypeError: 'ListField' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in defining `preSave` classmethod. You are trying to take a len from `hierarchy` `ListField` from `Place` class (not instance). This is because you are using the first argument of the method - it's not an instance, it's a class itself. Use the 3rd argument instead:

```
@classmethod
def preSave(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
    document.hierarchy_size = len(document.hierarchy)
```

Answer (score 0):

`len(object.field)` will retrieve all child documents and then count. If you only want the length of the array without retrieving all the documents you can use `len(object.to_mongo()["field"])`